# decimate data in python

Tags: python, downsampling

I put decimate in the title, but I am not sure that is exactly what I mean. Here is the full description of the issue. I have a dataframe that contains data from several subjects. What I want to do is to analyze data that is X number of days apart. The idea is that I only want to consider data that was collected every, say, 4th day from a subject. The catch here is that the data were collected in parallel for the subjects, so I can't just take every 4th day across subjects but rather need to do the decimation/downsampling/whatever for each subject. The two key columns in the dataframe are "subject" and "session_timestamp". In the latter, the date and time are formatted as in this example: 2017-11-10 16:30:47. Is there a good way to accomplish this in python?

Edit:
The first commenters asked for a more concrete example of the dataframe with some example data. Here is a toy dataframe that is similar to what I have and should be easy to work with. The code below creates a dataframe with 4 columns: subjectID, date, score1 and score2. Note that a subject can have more than one entry for a given date (basically, these are neural recordings and each row of the dataframe represents one neuron and we can record more than one neuron per subject)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ab = pd.DataFrame()
ab["subjectID"] = np.random.randint(5, size=200)#random list of "subjects" from 0 to 4
ab["date"] = np.random.randint(20, size=200)#random list of "dates" from 0 to 19
ab["score1"] = np.random.randint(200, size=200)#meant to simulate one measurement from one subject
ab["score2"] = np.random.randint(400, size=200)#meant to simulate a second measurement
```

What I want to do is to filter for the data (score1 and score2) that was collected at least 4 days apart for each subject. The code could be extremely simple and take the first day that a subject has an entry and every 4th day after that. But a better solution would be if it took the first day, then the next one that is more than 3 days later and then the one that is more than 3 days after that (not every subject has daily samples, so a rigid "every 4th day" code would not be so elegant). All data collected on the allowed days should be included. For example, all data with the day code 0 (if that is the first day of the subject) should be included.

Comment: This doesn't sound hard per se, but what to do depends entirely on how you have structured the data. A good Stack Overflow question should include a (small) set of sample data and your attempt at solving this in code so we can tell in more detail where you are stuck.

Comment: It would be much clearer if you show some records of your original dataframe and some records as example of what you want to get as result.

Comment: Did you mean you want a data frame subset that still contains all subjects, but has no more than one sample per 4 days? Or a subset that has only one subject and one sample / 4 days? Either way, this might be an interesting filter to try to code - and will likely require getting a list of dates with the correct spread first and using that as the selector for the final subset.

Comment: @Leo K. I edited the post and hopefully it is clear. But maybe I can step through an example. Let’s say I have subject 1 and subject 1 has data from dates 1 through 10. I want to take all data from subject 1 on Days 1, 5 and 9. Now let’s say subject 2 also has data on dates 1 through 10, I want all of his data on dates 1, 5 and 9 as well. Now let’s say subject 3 has data on dates 20-30. Fir him I want day 20, day 24 and day 28

Comment: @Leo K. The examples above are for a simple case. The ideal code should deal with a more complex scenario like a subject 4 who has data on days 1, 10 and 20. In his case, I want to keep all of the data because each entry is at least 4 days apart and all data from the same day should be kept. Does that make a bit more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a dataframe (with random data):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

ab = pd.DataFrame()
ab["subjectID"] = np.random.randint(5, size=200)#random list of "subjects" from 0 to 4
ab["day_number"] = np.random.randint(50, size=200)#random list of "dates" from 0 to 50
ab['real_date'] = ab.day_number.apply(lambda d: datetime(2018, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=d)) #to simulate real dates
ab["score1"] = np.random.randint(200, size=200)#meant to simulate one measurement from one subject
ab["score2"] = np.random.randint(400, size=200)#meant to simulate a second measurement

min_day = ab.real_date.min()
ab = ab.groupby(['subjectID', 'real_date']).sum() #because some subjects have more than 1 score each day

print(ab.head(10))

                      day_number  score1  score2
subjectID real_date                             
0         2018-01-01           0     306     273
          2018-01-04           3      32      60
          2018-01-05           4      61     135
          2018-01-08          21     477     393
          2018-01-09           8      22     341
          2018-01-10           9     137      30
          2018-01-11          30     281     674
          2018-01-14          13     183     396
          2018-01-15          14      41     337
          2018-01-16          15      83      50
```

Then fill the days when there are no data with the data of the next existing day:

```
df = ab.reset_index(level='subjectID').groupby('subjectID').resample('D').mean() #Complete missing dates with NaN
df = df.drop(columns='subjectID')
df = df.groupby(level='subjectID').fillna(method='bfill') #fills the NaN with the first next non NaN value
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer') #just to have ints, easier to read

print(df.head(10))

                      day_number  score1  score2
subjectID real_date                             
0         2018-01-01           0     306     273
          2018-01-02           3      32      60
          2018-01-03           3      32      60
          2018-01-04           3      32      60
          2018-01-05           4      61     135
          2018-01-06          21     477     393
          2018-01-07          21     477     393
          2018-01-08          21     477     393
          2018-01-09           8      22     341
          2018-01-10           9     137      30
```

Next resample (group by) periods of 4 days:

```
res = df.reset_index(level='subjectID').groupby('subjectID').resample('4D').first() #group by 4 days periods and keep only the first value
res = res.drop(columns='subjectID')
print(res.head(10))

                      day_number  score1  score2
subjectID real_date                             
0         2018-01-01           0     306     273
          2018-01-05           4      61     135
          2018-01-09           8      22     341
          2018-01-13          13     183     396
          2018-01-17          18      91      46
          2018-01-21          20      76     333
          2018-01-25          48     131     212
          2018-01-29          29      92      81
          2018-02-02          32     172      55
          2018-02-06          72      98     246
```

Finally reset the indexes and take care of the case when there are periods of more than 4 days with no data:

```
res = res.reset_index('real_date', drop=True) #the real_date has no meaning anymore
res['real_date'] = res.day_number.apply(lambda d: min_day + timedelta(days=d)) #good real_date based on the day_number
res = res.drop(columns='day_number')
res = res.set_index('real_date', append=True)
res = res.groupby(level=['subjectID', 'real_date']).first() #regroups periods with no data for more than 4 days

print(res.head(10))

                      score1  score2
subjectID real_date                 
0         2018-01-01     306     273
          2018-01-05      61     135
          2018-01-09      22     341
          2018-01-14     183     396
          2018-01-19      91      46
          2018-01-21      76     333
          2018-01-30      92      81
          2018-02-02     172      55
          2018-02-10      40     218
          2018-02-15     110     112
```

It is a little complicated, but I think this the best way to do it. I have no idea about the efficiency though, but it doesn't seem so bad.

Comment: This is a great start and has already given me clues about how to do it. I just wonder about the line "ab = ab.groupby(['subjectID', 'real_date']).sum()". This will take the sum of the two values on that date, yes? Is there a way around this? In my application, more than one independent sample can be taken on each day and I want to perserve that. This might also complicate the resample steps as well...

Comment: Ok then instead do `df = ab.groupby(['subjectID', 'real_date']).sum()` so you don't modify your initial dataframe, and build the `res` dataframe that I described. Once you have done this, you can use the index of `res` to filter `ab`, like so:
`ab = ab.set_index(['subjectID', 'real_date'])`
`ab = ab[ab.index.isin(res.index)]`

Comment: Thanks! It works well for me and I accepted the answer. Tried to upvote as well but I am too new to stack overflow for it to count. I am newish to python and some of the steps are still a little mysterious but it works in practice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you may be looking for is a way to sub-sample the population of your training examples. For this you may want to use some of the *imbalanced learning* methods, e.g.: ADASYN, SMOTE, Tomek link. random sub-/over-sampling, etc. (wikipedia article on [Oversampling and undersampling in data analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling_and_undersampling_in_data_analysis) gives a decent overview). There is a convenient implementation in [imbalanced-learn](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/) package.